# CheckBox's jquery onchange() not work in mozila firefox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

On checkbox `onchange()` event I am trying hide/show two textboxes but I facing problem. CheckBox's jQuery `onchange()` work in IE but not work in Mozilla firefox. I searched many article but not see any suitable answer . So what to do ?

Sorry for my bad English language.

```html
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_citfc" runat="server" onchange="citfc()" Text="is applicable" />
```

```js
function citfc() {
    $(function() {
        $('#<%=chk_citfc.ClientID %>').click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('#<%=TXT_CITFC.ClientID %>').show(1000);
                $('#<%=hfnumber.ClientID %>').show(1000);

            } else {
                $('#<%=TXT_CITFC.ClientID %>').hide(1000);
                $('#<%=hfnumber.ClientID %>').hide(1000);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry @RoryMcCrossan for posting wrong code. revised code added !

Comment: Have you defined `my()` within jQuery's ready handler? If so that's your issue - it needs to be within the scope of the `window` as you're using an `on*` event attribute

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_".

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan now it is working  But the browser says "ReferenceError: citfc is not defined"

Comment: can you upload your code to fiddler

Comment: What is `citfc`? I'm assuming it's a variable in your JS code you're attempting to use without defining it. Seeing a complete sample of your JS code would help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This.... It may Work

```
    function citfc() {

        if ($('#<%=chk_citfc.ClientID%>').is(':checked')) 
    {

            $("#<%=TXT_CITFC.ClientID%>").css("display", "block");

        }
        else
    {
            $("#<%=TXT_CITFC.ClientID%>").css("display", "none");             
        }
        }

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function(s, e) {
        citfc();
    });
```

Also Call the same function in Document Ready Function

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        citfc();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the current implementation unobtrusive `click` event handler is getting attached to element using inline `change` handler whenever `checked` state is changed.

To perform the desired option, use unobtrusive event handler and get rid of `onchange="citfc()"`.

*HTML*

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_citfc" runat="server" Text="is applicable" />
```

*Script*

```
$(function() {
    $('#<%=chk_citfc.ClientID %>').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#<%=TXT_CITFC.ClientID %>, #<%=hfnumber.ClientID %>').show(1000);
        } else {
            $('#<%=TXT_CITFC.ClientID %>, #<%=hfnumber.ClientID %>').hide(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

---

Or, Use the inline event handler propertly

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_citfc" runat="server" onchange="citfc(this)" Text="is applicable" />

function citfc(element) {
    if (element.checked)) {
        $('#<%=TXT_CITFC.ClientID %>, #<%=hfnumber.ClientID %>').show(1000);
    } else {
        $('#<%=TXT_CITFC.ClientID %>, #<%=hfnumber.ClientID %>').hide(1000);
    }
}
```